# Boost blocking read timeout

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am following the link below to implement a blocking read with timeout.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

It works fine. Now I want to implement another function that do not use timeout. so I have tried to call directly:

```
socket_.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buf,size),
         boost::bind(&TCPClient::HandleReceive, _1, _2, &ec, &length));
```

The problem is the function do not block and return immediately with length 0.

Which function should I call before async_receive to block indefinitely?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix `async` implies that the function runs asynchronously.

Simply call [`socket::receive`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive.html) instead.

If you need to read a fixed number of bytes before the call returns, you'd better look at [`asio::read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html), because the `receive` operation may not receive all of the requested number of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run.html) to wait for the work to complete.

Remember to [`reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html) the service before using it for more work, though.